# Find files by extension

Tags: unix

How can I modify the below command to find all files modified in last day that have extension of .log ?

Here is the command so far :

```
find . -mtime -1 -print
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find . -mtime -1 -iname '*.log'`

Note: Using double quotes instead of single quotes will likely give unexpected results due to shell expansion.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name \*.log -mtime -1 -print
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-name` option to find files by particular name

```
find . -mtime -1 -name "*.log" -print
```

Notice the use of wildcard character `*` to find all files ending with `.log`